# Help writing a matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

I have trouble in wrtiting this block matrix

[image]

Any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there probably is a pure LaTeX solution, one can try with tikz :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$\left(\tikz[scale=.9, baseline={(0,-.1)}]{\draw(-1,0)--(1,0) (0,-1)--(0,1)
(-.4,0) -- +(0,-1) (0,.4) -- +(1,0);\node at (-.5,.5) {T};
\node at (.5,-.5) {B}; \node at (-.2,-.5) {$a$};
\node at (.5,.2) {$a^t$};}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]